# Multidimensional Arrays two loops

Tags: php, while-loop

MSSQL query link is this;
[click here for picture](http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/9280/sqlsecreen.png)

and my output shows three different pictures for the same product as shown below. What I want is, if the product is the same, keep just one picture and then get the colors and sizes for that product.

Means;

My output ıs the picture below,

[click here for picture](http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/1445/while.png)

as you see there are three product in the picture but they are the same product with different colors and sizes, instead of seeing the same product every time, I want my output like in the picture below.

```
<table width="376" cellspacing="0"  class="stats" width:100%> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="9" align="center"><?php echo $secim ?></td> 
</tr> 
<?php 
while(odbc_fetch_into($sql_result, &$row)) { 
$unit1 = floor($row[3]); 
$unit2 = floor($row[4]); 
$unit3 = floor($row[5]); 
$unit4 = floor($row[6]); 
$unit5 = floor($row[7]); 
?> 
<tr> 
  <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><?php echo"$row[0]";?></td> 
  <td>36</td> 
  <td>38</td> 
  <td>40</td> 
  <td>42</td> 
  <td>44</td> 
</tr> 
<tr>       
<td width="114" align="right" valign="top">
<img src= <?php echo"images/Resize/$row[2]"?>></td> 
 <td width="25" valign="top"><?php echo"$row[1]";?></td> 
 <td width="25"valign="top"><?php echo"$unit1";?></td> 
 <td width="25"valign="top"><?php echo"$unit2";?></td> 
 <td width="25"valign="top"><?php echo"$unit3";?></td> 
 <td width="25"valign="top"><?php echo"$unit4";?></td> 
 <td width="25"valign="top"><?php echo"$unit5";?></td> 
 </tr> 
 <?php }  }?> 
 <?php  
 odbc_free_result($sql_result); 
 odbc_close($connection); 
 ?> 
 </table>
```

Comment: I know English isn't your first language. That's okay, but it's still difficult to understand your question. Perhaps you could try to clarify a bit more?

Comment: expanding on rdlowrey comment, can you show us the mysql query to fetch the data and an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: thanks but how do you want the output to look. What should it show? I am asking so I can see what you want from the loops.

Comment: still 404 `The requested URL /sql.png was not found on this server.`

Comment: SAciklama is where my product code area, there comes  for each one colour seperate line, i want SAciklama so product code come only one and the colour that belongs to this product comes in this loop. exit next code

Comment: Dude, [edit] your question to add additional information.  The edit link is right there below your tags.

Comment: this is how it looks as a result 
[click here for pic](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/85/tablex.png/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, http://jsfiddle.net/sv8ZS/

```
while(odbc_fetch_into($sql_result, &$row)) { 
$unit1 = floor($row[3]); 
$unit2 = floor($row[4]); 
$unit3 = floor($row[5]); 
$unit4 = floor($row[6]); 
$unit5 = floor($row[7]); 
?> 
//you can check with the index to see if its a first row or not
//This will avoid printing the same header for each row.
if (this-is-the-first row) {
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><?php echo"$row[0]";?></td> 
    <td>36</td> 
    <td>38</td> 
    <td>40</td> 
    <td>42</td> 
    <td>44</td> 
  </tr> 
} 
//above if ends
<tr>  
//If its not a first row then do not show the image again and merge all the next rows
if (this-is-the-first-row) {     
   <td width="114" align="right" valign="top" rowspan='3'>
    <img src= <?php echo"images/Resize/$row[2]"?>
   </td>  
 }
 //above if ends 
 <td width="25" valign="top"><?php echo"$row[1]";?></td> 
 <td width="25"valign="top"><?php echo"$unit1";?></td> 
 <td width="25"valign="top"><?php echo"$unit2";?></td> 
 <td width="25"valign="top"><?php echo"$unit3";?></td> 
 <td width="25"valign="top"><?php echo"$unit4";?></td> 
 <td width="25"valign="top"><?php echo"$unit5";?></td> 
 </tr> 
 <?php }  }?>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help i will try tomorrow 
appreciate

Comment: @salihhanifeoglu:Have you implemented the changes I suggested? Did it work?

Comment: @omer thank you very much for your help i will  appreciate  
 I couldn't make it because i couldn't find the first element. (first element in db fild name 'sAciklama' ) I am going to send you a shorter code. I made the program shorter, what should i write to find the first record?

Comment: The first record means the first row of the table. For that, you can set the $i = 0 before the while loop and put $i++ before while loop ends (ending curly brace of while). So, this `if (this-is-the-first row)` will be replaced with `if ($i === 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
<?php
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Model</th>
<th>Color</th>
<th>Unit</th>
</tr>";
?>
<?php
while($row =odbc_fetch_array($result)){
//if $row['sAciklama']=$row['sAciklama'] bla bla ???
if (this-is-the-first row) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sAciklama'] . "</td>"; //Model First Element 
}
if (this-is-the-first-row) {  
echo "<td>" . $row['sRenkAdi'] . "</td>"; //color
echo "<td>" . $row['Kalan'] . "</td>";    //unit
echo "</tr>";
}}
echo "</table>";
?>
```